# Automatically add a row on Data Grid View C#

Tags: c#, xml, forms, datagridview

Basically I'm creating  form application that allows for an XML file to be uploaded, then the contents of the XML file to be displayed in data grid view.

This is my code to search for and open the file.

```
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Filter = "XML | *.xml";
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            XmlDocument xDOC = new XmlDocument();
            xDOC.Load(ofd.FileName);

            int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = xDOC.InnerText;

        }
```

And here is the XML:

```
<people>
 <person> David </person>
 <person> Joey </person>
 <person> Adam </person>
</people>
```

I've managed to get it working, but for some reason all the contents of the XML file show up on the same row! Help?!

Comment: What did you expect [`XmlDocument.InnerText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.innertext%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to return?

Comment: Please post your xml

Comment: You are adding only one row to the DataGridView, how could it work any differently?

Comment: Could you provide some help, Otiel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you are adding the whole content (InnerText) of your file in the same cell. You have to take the content of the Nodes you want.

Something like this should work :

```
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.Filter = "XML | *.xml";
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        XmlDocument xDOC = new XmlDocument();
        xDOC.Load(ofd.FileName);

        //We loop through each person node of our document
        foreach(XmlNode node in xDOC.SelectNodes("people/person"))
        {
            //And add its content to a new row
            int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = node.InnerText;
        }

    }
```

What we do is provide the XPath of the items we want to the SelectNode function. Think of it like a file path but for Xml.

I will advise you to have a look on the [System.Linq.Xml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq(v=vs.110).aspx) namespace and particularly the [XDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx) class which in my opinion provides a more simple way to work with Xml.

Comment: Still isn't working. :/ in my XML file the nodes under 'people' are all named 'person', so that's probably why they're still showing up in the same line with the code you provided.

Comment: My bad, I have not worked with xml document for too long. See my edit, it should work now